# Mount and access similar BTRFS filesystem

Tags: btrfs

Say that I duplicated a disk to a new disk (using *dd* or similar), and have been using the new disk for a while. But, then I decide I want to view a file or files on the old disk quickly, specifically in a BTRFS partition.

How do I mount the old BTRFS partition so that the live BTRFS filesystem doesn't treat the old partition as part of the filesystem, but lets the mount live in isolation in its own separate mount point?

A simple mount will incorporate all of the old snapshots into the BTRFS system, so that if I try to navigate to the mount point, I will see files from the latest snapshot (i.e. from the new disk).

Comment: Just mount. If the volume is not part of btrfs raid (which I have no experience with), the volume should mount just fine. And as you mentioned, all subvolumes will be accessible too. You can get a list of them with `sudo btrfs subvolume list <path inside the mount point>`

Comment: [That's what I'm saying](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116014/13308): it doesn't mount just fine. The two partitions merge their data and intermingle their snapshots.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. It looks like a bug on part of btrfs. If I were you, I'd ask on the https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs_mailing_list (and if you do, please post some feedback here as well!)